# Network ERROR uploading image with external URL Strapi

Tags: image, heroku, url, deployment, strapi

I am using Strapi as CMS for my corporate Website, everything works fine, expect the fact that i am getting a Network Error ( Like on the screenshot ) everytime i am trying to upload an image using an external link ( like this one : https://auparchemin.ci/assets/480x960.jpg ).
[See the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhB6x.png)

I can't use the manual upload because my website is served by Heroku, and from what i heard heroku file system is only temporary.

Thanks for the help,